# Android crashes when trying to get data from YouTube?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I got this snippet, which was supposed to toast out titles of certain videos from youtube.

```
 public static void getVids() {
        try {
            YouTubeService myService = new YouTubeService("mycompany-myapp-1");
            String myFeed = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos?start-index=1&max-results=25&vq=lizards&oi=spell";
            printVideoFeed(myService, myFeed);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(null, "Error "+ex.toString(), 5000);
            toast.show();
        } catch (ServiceException ex) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(null, "Error "+ex.toString(), 5000);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    private static void printVideoFeed(YouTubeService service, String feedUrl) throws IOException, ServiceException {
        VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
        List<VideoEntry> allVideos = videoFeed.getEntries();
        Iterator<VideoEntry> itAllVideos = allVideos.iterator();
        String Titles = "";
        while (itAllVideos.hasNext()){
            VideoEntry oneVideo  = itAllVideos.next();
            TextConstruct oneVideoTitle = oneVideo.getTitle();
            Titles = Titles + " | " + oneVideoTitle.toString();
        }

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(null, "Working! " + Titles , 5000);
        toast.show();

    }
```

But it crashes when I execute it. Here's what logcat says:

```
08-05 17:33:30.203: INFO/dalvikvm(13832): Failed resolving Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource; interface 1435 'Ljavax/activation/DataSource;'
08-05 17:33:30.207: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): Link of class 'Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource;' failed
08-05 17:33:30.207: INFO/dalvikvm(13832): Failed resolving Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/BaseMediaSource; interface 452 'Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource;'
08-05 17:33:30.207: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): Link of class 'Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/BaseMediaSource;' failed
08-05 17:33:30.207: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaStreamSource; (435)
08-05 17:33:30.207: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): Link of class 'Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaStreamSource;' failed
08-05 17:33:30.207: ERROR/dalvikvm(13832): Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaStreamSource', referenced from method com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource
08-05 17:33:30.207: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 453 (Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaStreamSource;) in Lcom/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService;
08-05 17:33:30.207: DEBUG/dalvikvm(13832): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0013
08-05 17:33:30.207: DEBUG/dalvikvm(13832): VFY: dead code 0x0015-0039 in Lcom/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService;.getMediaResource (Ljava/net/URL;Lcom/google/gdata/util/ContentType;Lcom/google/gdata/data/DateTime;)Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource;
08-05 17:33:30.210: INFO/dalvikvm(13832): Failed resolving Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource; interface 1435 'Ljavax/activation/DataSource;'
08-05 17:33:30.210: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): Link of class 'Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource;' failed
08-05 17:33:30.210: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource;)
08-05 17:33:30.210: INFO/dalvikvm(13832): Failed resolving Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource; interface 1435 'Ljavax/activation/DataSource;'
08-05 17:33:30.210: WARN/dalvikvm(13832): Link of class 'Lcom/google/gdata/data/media/MediaSource;' failed
08-05 17:33:30.210: INFO/dalvikvm(13832): Could not find method com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaSource.getName, referenced from method com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.initMediaRequest
```

...

What do you think might be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The solution should be to replace your JavaMail libraries with the ones found [here](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list) (JavaMail for Android).

Comment: Hmm... replaced, same problem. :(

Comment: Ah, that sucks. In which case I'd look into using [GData for Android](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the YouTube API team: "My understanding is that the Java Google Data client library isn't currently compatible with the Android runtime environment."

[This link](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/85f0552c6b2c6c0b) is where I found that answer as well as the error messages you're seeing.